# Convert Header file .h to C#

Tags: c#, c, header, converters

I am having a lot of header files (written in C) that I want to convert into C# code.
The header files contains enums, structs, methods.

I can convert them by hand, but that would take forever, so i was wondering if there is a tool to convert header files into C#.

I have tried [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) but that only works with /clr compiled .dlls.

I have tried [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) and that works some of the way, it succesfully generates nice enums, but the structs and methods doesn't look very good.

Is there other ways I can convert header .h files?

Comment: There is no general solutions to this problem. Handcraft seems to be your choice.

Comment: Well it doesn't need to work out of the box, I can make tweeks and fixes here and there (including adding <Summery> ...</summery>). But anything that can be auto generated would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: If you're mostly satisfied with the output of SWIG and it's less work use SWIG then correct the definitions that are amiss.

Comment: SWIG generates the enums very nicely, and I am using the enums it generates. But I still need the structs and methods.